# Bootstrap scrollspy navigation not working in fixed navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, scrollspy

I use a bootstrap navigation here: https://bm-translations.de/km

I set the following like [official manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/), to automatically updateBootstrap navigation or list group components based on scroll position to indicate which link is currently active in the viewport. But it doesnt work:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar">
```

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two questions here: (1) Have you accounted for the TypeError in your JS?  (2) Why are you targeting `#myNavbar` instead of its parent `#nav_bar`

Comment: (1) Yes I know about this error, its because this function is for the homepage and not used on this subpage. (2) I changed it without any success

Comment: Scrolling up and down with the inspector active shows the CSS classes being applied and removed correctly.  Have you reviewed your non-Bootstrap customizations to ensure that you aren't inadvertently breaking ScrollSpy behavior?  Also, you seem to be using Bootstrap 3 so make sure your manual references reflect that (you linked to 4.x)

Comment: @RobertC I cant see any class change with inspector. Where do you see this? My customizations only affect the class stylings. And I thought scrollspy is also possible with bootstrap 3, isnt it? And I added it manually in globalcss.css and globaljs.js   
Which part of bootstrap is supporting the scrollspy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the absolute urls in the nav links. They should contain only the hash instead of the full url..

`<a itemprop="url" href="#video">`

If you *must* use the absolute url, you can specify the Scrollspy anchors in the `data-target` instead...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="" itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="https://bm-translations.de/km#video" data-target="#video">Leistungen</a>
        <ul>
            ..
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name" class="active"><a itemprop="url" href="https://bm-translations.de/km#ueber-mich" data-target="#ueber-mich">Über mich</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name" class=""><a itemprop="url" href="https://bm-translations.de/km#kosten" data-target="#kosten">Preise</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name" class=""><a itemprop="url" href="https://bm-translations.de/km#kontakt" data-target="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```